# Vim hides files with curly braces in path

Tags: vim

I am using vim with Nerdtree and FuzzyFinder.

I have files in path `foo/{id,id}/`

When I open the path with nerd tree the files inside that path are not showing. The same happens with FuzzyFinder.

I presume the curly braces are doing something strange, possibly a find/replace?

Has anyone else experienced this and is there a fix so that I can see the files?

Heres some versions:

- OS X 10.8.4
- zsh 5.0.2
- VIM 7.3
- NERD Tree 4.2.0
- FuzzyFinder 4.2.2

Comment: Operating system and plugin versions, please!

Comment: I use Fuf 4.2.2 and NERD_tree 4.2.0+, and a file `{id,ga}` is showing up correctly in both, on Windows 7 and Ubuntu 13.04, with Vim 7.3.823.

Comment: Its actually files inside the curly braced path I cannot see. i.e. foo/{id,id}/bar.txt

Comment: Ah, that wasn't entirely clear. I can now reproduce, with NERD_tree on both Windows and Linux (the folder is there, but it's empty), Fuf works on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to missed / wrong escaping. Many (Unix) shells expand `{foo,bar}`; this is called *brace expansion*. Vim has functions like `fnameescape()`, but they don't work for all (especially such corner) cases. You should probably file a bug on the plugins' issue trackers.